# Italic/bold font in Lyx

Tags: fonts, lyx, bold, italic

I am using the latest version of lyx and I have selected a custom roman font in the settings menu in my document. I am using this font: http://www.fontspace.com/roger-white/oxford

The problem I am encountering is that in the compiled PDF italic and bold text doesn't appear italic or bold, they appear without any special formatting. I know my font 'supports' bold/italic as I have the same font selected to use in the lyx editor and bold and italics show up properly.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: Perhaps the font actually doesn't have these features, and LyX just fakes the italic and bold fonts in the editor. (Don't know it this is correct, hence posting it as a comment, not an answer.)

Comment: From the link that you provided. There does not appear to be an italic version nor a bold version of the font.

Comment: The faked bold and italics in the editor look good enough for my use. Is there any way to make lyx use them in the PDF? I have tried adding \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{Oxford} to the preamble, but this has no effect...

Comment: For anyone who reached here searching for how to make a line of text bold or italic, the answer is to select the text, right click on it and select the options to customize the text as shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLD3wtjbGxo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opening the font in [Font Manager](http://code.google.com/p/font-manager/) it appears that the Oxford font does not have bold and italic features -- these show as being provided by the rendering library, as opposed to being provided by a font file. I would guess that LyX just fakes these features in the editor view.

As you yourself mention in a comment, `fontspec` (the package that handles loading of True Type and Open Type fonts) can fake these features, by adding to the preamble

```
\setmainfont[AutoFakeBold,AutoFakeSlant]{Oxford}
```

Note that you have to use the XeTeX engine for this to work (at least the fake bold), so use *View --> View (Other formats) --> PDF (XeTeX)*, and the equivalent for updating. This does not work with the LuaTeX engine.